# Single icon sound player in html using font awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want a single icon sound player which when a user click plays a sound file...
The only requirement is that it should be pure HTML CSS only... No JavaScript please

```
<a href="test.mp3"><i class="fa fa-sound"></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but only using javascript. you can do it using following code:

```
    <audio id="player" src="Kalimba.mp3"></audio>
    <div>
         <a onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><i class='fa fa-volume-up fa-2x'></i></a>
     </div>
```

Good Luck!

**Edit:**

The href colour will make it blue. you need to add custom css rule to change it back to black. 
Google that.

For Example:

```
a {
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Comment: @MG425 Updated my answer,