# javascript inside php - failing

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Here's my code in side of my php file:

```
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo '<audio id="player" src="../cdh/ba1.mp3"></audio>';
        echo '<a onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><i class='fa fa-lg fa-volume-up'>';
        echo '</script>';
```

I was basing this off of Ionuț G. Stan's answer on [How to output JavaScript with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164130/how-to-output-javascript-with-php) and Sykox's answer on [Single icon sound player in html using font awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666629/single-icon-sound-player-in-html-using-font-awesome). I just took out the `div`s changed the `src` & `i class`.

The line giving me issues has got to be:

```
echo '<a onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><i class='fa fa-lg fa-volume-up'>';
```

which gives the error:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';''

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: You need to escape the encapsulation quote type in your string. Look at the color highlighting of your question. In particular here `getElementById('`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape a single quote ( ' ) in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134910/how-to-escape-a-single-quote-in-javascript)

Comment: I suggest using a good IDE so that these simple errors are caught: PHPStorm is a perfect choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape single quotes inside.

```
echo '<a onclick="document.getElementById(\'player\').play()"><i class=\'fa fa-lg fa-volume-up\'></i></a>';
```

Or you can even use double quotes.

```
echo '<a onclick="document.getElementById("player").play()"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-volume-up"></i></a>';
```

PS: You have to close `<a>` tag as well.

Change your code to

```
echo '<a onclick="playAudio();"><i class=\'fa fa-lg fa-volume-up\'></i></a>'; 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'function playAudio(){var audio = new Audio("../cdh/ba1.mp3");'; 
echo 'audio.play();}'; 
echo '</script>';
```

The icon is not printing because it is under script tags.

Comment: please find updated code you forgot to close the `<a>` tag

Comment: awesomefont icon still not loading. ?~~?

Comment: have you included fontawesome library. with the limited code I just can't debug. share your full code

Comment: i tried executing it @MrLister but it doesn't give me any error. Can you please confirm again??

Comment: @Abhishek what's live? btw yes my FA lib is working fine before my <?php I have html code `<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>` that works absolutely a-ok

Comment: @user3306356 have you tried the second way by using double quotes maybe MrLister is right..

Comment: No worries @MrLister Enjoy your coffee..!!

Comment: @user3306356 can you please update the question with the full source code?? because its running for me everywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133754/discussion-between-user3306356-and-abhishek).